# ADFS2 secondary server not listening on port 443

Tags: ssl-certificate, adfs, ssl-certificate-renewal

Our monitoring sensor connection for https 443 to our secondary ADFS server is refused.

We recently renewed theADFS SSL certificate, and since the secondary server is not listening on port 443.

All changes appeared to have been replicated successfully and correctly from the primary server.  i.e. can see New SSL is bound to port 443, and ADFS service restarted.

The servers are in AWS, both have the same security group rules, also local Windows firewall permits inbound 443.

Have disabled AV.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that IIS is running? Have you verified that there is a process listening on port 443?

Comment: Hi,But IIS is not used by ADFS with 2012 and beyond.

Comment: OK. Have you confirmed that there is a process listening on port 443?

Comment: 443 is not listening, but adfs service is running.